# Vertical Gradient to a ListFieldItem in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, gradient, listfield

I want to display a Vertical Gradient as the background for a ListField Row in BlackBerry.   I have used shadedFillPath function to achieve this, but failed:

```
int[] cols = new int[]{0xFFFFFF, 0xEEEEEE,0xEEEEEE,0XDDDDDD };
int[] xInds = new int[]{0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getWidth(), 0};
int[] yInds = new int[]{focusRect.y, focusRect.y,    
this.getRowHeight()+focusRect.y,this.getRowHeight()+focusRect.y};
graphics.drawShadedFilledPath(xInds, yInds,null, cols, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        int[] X_PTS = { 0, getPreferredWidth(),getPreferredWidth(),0};        
        int[] Y_PTS = { 0,0, getPreferredHeight(),getPreferredHeight()};        
        int[] drawColors = { Colors.CategoryFocusGradientStart, Colors.CategoryFocusGradientStart,
                             Colors.CategoryFocusGradientEnd, Colors.CategoryFocusGradientEnd };        
        try {            
            g.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS, Y_PTS, null, drawColors, null);        
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.Error(e,this,"Bad arguments.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not the @rfsk2010 answer , but nearly (you must change that 0's for y):

Into:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics,int index, int y, int width)
```

Do this:

```
int[] X_PTS = { 0, getPreferredWidth(),getPreferredWidth(),0};        
int[] Y_PTS = { y, y, getPreferredHeight(),getPreferredHeight()};        
int[] drawColors = { Colors.CategoryFocusGradientStart, Colors.CategoryFocusGradientStart,
                     Colors.CategoryFocusGradientEnd, Colors.CategoryFocusGradientEnd };        
try {            
    graphics.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS, Y_PTS, null, drawColors, null);        
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.Error(e,this,"Bad arguments.");
}
```